# Download file with firefox or chromium snap to smb share

Tags: permissions, firefox, samba, snap, chromium

Firefox and chromium are installable exclusively as snaps in Ubuntu 22.04.
As it seems, this leads to the following problem: files can not be up- or downloaded to or from a smb share directly.
The smb shares are connected via bookmarks in Nautilus. Mounting shares with entries in fstab is not helpful here.

What happens:

After specifying an smb share as destination and hitting "Download" or "Save", the download dialog disappears: no progress bar, no file at the destination.

What works:

- up- and downloading to and from smb share via drag and drop
- up- and downloading to or from a local directory

What I tried:
granting Chromium every right in "Ubuntu Software" / Permissions, like "Access the network manager". At least any right I could see - Chromium's list doesn't display fully on my FullHD-Screen, there is no scrollbar, arrow keys won't help , and there could be more settings below "Read/write access toU2F devices exposed" - which I can't see.

Is there any way to facilitate the behavior one would expect? (i.e. simply download files to anywhere I want)
Maybe some setting for smb on my side, or on the server side, or for snap?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously one has to mount smb shares with fstab.
Using Nautilus' feature of connecting to a smb server in "Other Places" and bookmarking it is not sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite correct. Mounting a drive in the way you describe is as effective as mounting it in fstab. The problem is associated with the sandboxing of the snap and some snaps have an option to allow access to other than the drive on which the snap is installed.

Comment: You write: "some snaps".
I wrote: granting Chromium every right in "Ubuntu Software" / Permissions, like "Access the network manager".  

Didn't help (and with firefox it was the same...)

Comment: You said in your question "Mounting shares with entries in fstab is not helpful here." So this answer is a bit surprising...

Comment: You are right. Not helpful in the first place because mounting per fstab didn't work anymore. After some editing it did again :-)